# Installing kde-full after upgrading to 15.04 Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 15.04

I just upgraded to Kubuntu 15.04, and some (kde) packages are gone. I used to install them using

```
sudo apt-get install kde-full
```

But kde-full is not on the list. How to fix that?

`kubuntu-full` also does not install anything.

Comment: Install the packages separately.

Comment: @A.B. What are those packages?

Comment: Everything that you miss. =)

Answer (score 0):

It appears `kde-full` is now depreciated and my guess is the packagers just use kubuntu-desktop or an [alternate metapackage](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/kde-full).

I suggest you ask on the mailing list if you do not get an answer here.

I did not see a discussion on the [various](https://community.kde.org/Kubuntu) [wiki](https://qa.debian.org/developer.php?login=debian-qt-kde@lists.debian.org) [pages](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/kubuntu-devel).

Comment: It was good in a sense you didn't have to install packages one by one. And also I don't understand why kubuntu-full still on the list, but does absolutely nothing.

Comment: to be honest, most people use kubuntu-desktop . I have seen kdm-full used in years. Last time I saw it used was when people wanted to do a "minimal install" and they then wanted kde with all the bells and whistles but without all the customizations of kubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-full
```

This did the trick for me

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! OP mentioned that `kubuntu-full` didn't fix his problem, which means that `sudo apt0get install kubuntu-full` didn't work